# Determine if SQL Server login has permission to create a database

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2022

Does this query determine if a SQL Server login can execute the CREATE DATABASE command?

```
select the_login.name as the_login_name,
  the_login.principal_id as the_login_principal_id,
  case sysadmin_role_assoc.role_principal_id
    when null then 0 else 1 end as user_has_sysadmin_role,
  case serveradmin_role_assoc.role_principal_id
    when null then 0 else 1 end as user_has_serveradmin_role,
  case dbcreator_role_assoc.role_principal_id
    when null then 0 else 1 end as user_has_dbcreator_role,
  case the_diskadmin_role_assoc.role_principal_id
    when null then 0 else 1 end as user_has_diskadmin_role,
  case alter_any_database_perm.grantee_principal_id
    when null then 0 else 1 end as user_has_alter_any_database

from master.sys.server_principals the_login

  left outer join  sys.server_principals the_sysadmin_role
   on (the_sysadmin_role.name = 'sysadmin')

  left outer join  sys.server_role_members sysadmin_role_assoc
   on (the_login.principal_id = sysadmin_role_assoc.member_principal_id
   and the_sysadmin_role.principal_id = sysadmin_role_assoc.role_principal_id)

  left outer join  sys.server_principals the_serveradmin_role
   on (the_serveradmin_role.name = 'serveradmin')

  left outer join  sys.server_role_members serveradmin_role_assoc
   on (the_login.principal_id = serveradmin_role_assoc.member_principal_id
   and the_serveradmin_role.principal_id = serveradmin_role_assoc.role_principal_id)

  left outer join  sys.server_principals the_dbcreator_role
   on (the_dbcreator_role.name = 'dbcreator')

  left outer join  sys.server_role_members dbcreator_role_assoc
   on (the_login.principal_id = dbcreator_role_assoc.member_principal_id
   and the_dbcreator_role.principal_id = dbcreator_role_assoc.role_principal_id)

  left outer join  sys.server_principals the_diskadmin_role
   on (the_diskadmin_role.name = 'diskadmin')

  left outer join  sys.server_role_members the_diskadmin_role_assoc
   on (the_login.principal_id = the_diskadmin_role_assoc.member_principal_id
   and the_diskadmin_role.principal_id = the_diskadmin_role_assoc.role_principal_id)

  left outer join sys.server_permissions alter_any_database_perm
   on (the_login.principal_id=alter_any_database_perm.grantee_principal_id
   and alter_any_database_perm.permission_name = 'alter any database'
   and alter_any_database_perm.state_desc='grant')

  where the_login.name='sa';
```

If the third, fourth, fifth, sixth, or seventh column of this query is "1", then the login named in the WHERE clause has permission to execute CREATE DATABASE.

I need this query to set up the automatic creation of a SQL Server database.  The name of the SQL Server host and the name of the login and the password are required for setting up the creation; this query is to validate that an acceptable login has been entered.

Comment: Is the user logged in, or do you need to check this from another login?

Comment: Logins in the `sysadmin` role for example are never going to return a match, so you're going to have to check if they are in that role. Or in a group that inherits. etc. Just wait until you have to reverse engineer logins that get access to the server via AD groups.

Comment: Keep in mind that create table and create user are database-level permissions, so you won't be checking those at server scope.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Realistically is it easier to just run a cursor and do `EXECUTE AS ... fn_my_permissions ... REVERT` for each?

Comment: @Charlieface never tried it to see if it truly does that correctly (there are some limitations with `EXECUTE AS` - it is not full login emulation). But also where do you execute the database-level checks? A specified database? All databases?

Comment: Good point. If you have `CREATE DATABASE` permissions then you can be the database owner, so for that DB you can do what you want.

Comment: I would file it is, if you have to ask, you can't afford it. Just do the action you want to do to find out

Comment: @Charlieface The user who tries to `CREATE DATABASE` *is* logged in.  The alternate solution I can think of is just to execute `CREATE DATABASE`, and if there is an error, search the error message for the phrase `CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand (1) Do you know the queries to determine if the login has the sysadmin role? (2) I am assuming that the creator of the database has permission to create the user in the database and the new user can be granted permission to create the tables.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Zsg6fwGh This works for a sysadmin also. It only works if you are logged in, or if you use `EXECUTE AS` to impersonate the login. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The question asked in the duplicate may be about C#, but all of the answers provide pure SQL solutions.